# Python program has values in list before return statement (checked with print), but original calling method shows an empty list after return

Tags: python, return, return-value, maze

I am writing a simple maze solving program for school. The method should bounce a ray of light off of mirrors (-1 is -45degrees, 1 is 45 degrees, 0 is empty space) and for some reason I cannot solve this last little issue; the exit case.

The move direction methods I have removed because SO said that I have too much code. I can include it if need be.

When the final move goes from the moveRight method into isAngled, the list has the full path. I can print it there or access an index of the final list in either of these last two methods. When I return from isAngled however, my list is empty in maze_solver and I am having a hard time seeing why.

Ive tried reading online and making a bunch of changes, I am using a jupyterlab notebook, windows 10, python 3.8.3

Here is the code, I appreciate any help!

```
#oreintation denotes direction light is headed 1: right, 2: left, 3:down, 4:up 5:end of maze
#loc[0] is x
#loc[1] is y

#helper functions for moving in a given direction
def moveRight(maze,loc,path):
    if loc[1]+1 < len(maze[0]):
        isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]+1),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]+1],1)
    else:
        return isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]],5)
        #print(path)

def moveLeft(maze,loc,path):
    if loc[1]-1 >= 0:
        isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]-1),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]-1],2)
    else:
        return isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]],5)

def moveDown(maze,loc,path):
    if loc[0]+1 < len(maze):
        isAngled(path, maze, (loc[0]+1, loc[1]),maze[loc[0]+1][loc[1]],3)
    else:
        return isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]],5)
        print(path)
def moveUp(maze,loc,path):
    if loc[0]-1 >= 0:
        isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0]-1,loc[1]),maze[loc[0]-1][loc[1]],4)
    else:
        return isAngled(path,maze,(loc[0],loc[1]),maze[loc[0]][loc[1]],5)
        
#add location to the route, then check if it contains a mirror and turn accordingly
def isAngled(path, maze,loc,nextNum, orientation):
    #path.append(loc)
    
    if orientation ==5: #this is my exit case
        print(path[3]) #My full list is still available here
        return path
    else:
        path.append(loc)
    
    #moving to the right
    if  (nextNum) < 0 and orientation == 1:
        moveDown(maze,(loc), path)
    elif (nextNum) > 0 and orientation ==1:
        moveUp(maze,loc,path)
    elif orientation == 1:
        moveRight(maze, (loc), path)
    #moving to the left  
    if (nextNum) < 0 and orientation == 2:
        moveUp(maze,loc,path)
    elif (nextNum) > 0 and orientation ==2:
        moveDown(maze,loc,path)
    elif orientation ==2:
        moveLeft(maze,loc,path)
    #moving downawrds
    if (nextNum) > 0 and orientation == 3:
        moveLeft(maze,loc,path)
    elif (nextNum) < 0 and orientation ==3:
        moveRight(maze, loc, path)   
    elif orientation ==3:
        moveDown(maze,loc,path)
    #moving upwards
    if nextNum > 0 and orientation ==4:
        moveRight(maze,loc,path)
    elif nextNum < 0 and orientation ==4:
        moveLeft(maze,loc, path)
    elif orientation == 4:
        moveUp(maze,loc,path)
        
#execute the program. maze always starts at (0,0) and heading to the right.
def maze_solver(maze):
    path = []
    newpath = isAngled(path, maze, (0,0), maze[0][0], 1) #enter maze headed right, check if first square is a mirror
    #newpath, or the value of this isangled method call are both none here
    return newpath
    
    
maze = [
[ 0, 0, 0, -1],
[ 1, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 1, 0],
[-1, 0, 0, 1]]
done = maze_solver(maze)
print(done)
```

output:
(0, 3)

None

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code does not run.  It is not minimal.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, will update right now. I have traced the issue, when maze_solver calls isAngled, no value is provided Yet when isAngled returns path, it is fully populated.

Comment: Do not *describe* the trace, *post* it: both code and output.  Again, refer to the MRE link.

Comment: I figured it out with some help. I was redefining the list in my maze_solver method. it should have been like this:   def maze_solver(maze):
    path = []
    isAngled(path, maze, (0,0), maze[0][0], 1) 
    return path